# Camel : Invoke one route from another and get back response synchronously

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, eip

I have two route A and B as below

```
from("some endpoint")  //route A
.to("direct:x")

from("direct:x")  //route B
.doTry()
   .bean("somebean")  //set Custom object PQR as message body 
.doCatch()
   .bean("some other bean")  //log exception
.end()
```

Now I want to invoke route B once route A is complete (already done). Now how to get the response PQR object (only if route B succeeds) back from route B in route A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to do that automatically. If you chain another `to` in route A after the `to("direct:x")` , it will take the response from route B. You can try logging the body after the `to("direct:x")` and check the result.